# extra CFLAGs with Makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm reading through Foundations of GTK+ and in so doing decided to write a simple makefile that would let me run "make " to compile the example program I'd just written. I also stumbled upon a list of compiler directives [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html) that the Gnome team specified will help moving from GTK2 to GTK3, so I wanted to include those.

I'm a make noob for all intents and purposes, so this is what I came up with:

```
CC           = gcc
CFLAGS      += -Wall
GTK_DFLAGS   = -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DGTK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DGSEAL_ENABLE
GTK_CFLAGS   = $(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)
GTK_LDFLAGS  = $(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(GTK_DFLAGS) $(GTK_CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%: %.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(GTK_DFLAGS) $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(GTK_LDFLAGS) -o $@ $< 

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~
```

And as you might guess, it doesn't work quite right. I know running pkg-config from inside the makefile isn't an ideal solution, but this is for my small-scale learning projects and not for deployment of any sort. That said, the output is weird to me; it seems like make just ignores any variables after CFLAGS.

Something like:

```
[patrick@blackbox ch2]$ make helloworld
gcc -Wall    helloworld.c   -o helloworld
helloworld.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'helloworld' failed
make: *** [helloworld] Error 1
```

If I add have the contents of GTK_DFLAGS simply tacked onto the end of CFLAGS, they appear on the command line, but the pkg-config variables are still missing.

It's obvious to me that I messed something simple up, but after an hour of vaguely worded Googling, I'm fresh out of ideas as to what it is.

Comment: Also, I'd be happy to have anything _else_ I'm doing wrong pointed out. =)

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors off the top of my head.  I would recommend using `:=` instead of `=` on the lines with `$(shell ...)`.  Getting that wrong only results in extra calls to `pkg-config`, though, which is just a performance problem during `make`.  Not the root cause of whatever's causing this problem.

Comment: Aha... I see what's going on.  Your main target is `helloworld` and you're compiling it directly from the `helloworld.c` file, rather than linking a `helloworld.o` file.  What's your `helloworld` target look like?

Comment: That's the whole makefile, and the command I'm invoking to use it, haha. I sense an answer arriving shortly. ;D

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, and of course the vocabulary I was missing when asking this question/doing earlier searches.

```
CC           = gcc
CFLAGS      += -Wall -std=c11
GTK_DFLAGS   = -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DGTK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DGSEAL_ENABLE
GTK_CFLAGS  := $(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0)
GTK_LDFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(GTK_DFLAGS) $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(GTK_LDFLAGS) -o $* $*.c

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *~
```

This does what I want, which is to compile a single .c file of any name into a program of the same name with the GTK flags I was looking to use.

Thanks to those who contributed!

Comment: You should write the rule as `% : %.c`.  If you don't give a prerequisite then make won't rebuild your program when you modify the source file, which makes it sort of useless to use a makefile in the first place.

Comment: Ah, sure enough! I made that change to my makefile after make told me the target was up to date, but I forgot to make the change here. Doing so! =)

Answer (score 0):

You need a target for `helloworld` in your Makefile.  Something like this:

```
helloworld: helloworld.o
    $(CC) -o helloworld helloworld.o $(LDFLAGS) $(GTK_LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: But if I just want make to build whatever I provide to it? For instance, "make helloworld" compiles helloworld.c with the provided directives, but "make foo" will compile foo.c with the same directives.

Comment: If your executable can be made from just a single source file, then it seems like your `%: %.o` rule should cover it.  My memory is fuzzy here, but I believe those pattern rules require a suffix on both sides, and that's something that rule lacks.

Comment: Yeah, I solved it. I was mistaken in my understanding of the macros. See my answer below. =)